# Is there a publicly accessible event to mark a ModalDialog close?

Tags: c#, xaml, sitecore, modal-dialog

I recently made a custom ribbon in Sitecore. The two buttons in it fire off a command which activate a Xaml application using `SheerResponse.ShowModalDialog`. These applications effect the state of a database being read by another component on the ribbon.

I either need to be able to fire a custom event or function from the Xaml application to make the other ribbon component, or I need to be able to make the component on the ribbon aware that it needs to re-render when the `ModalDialog`s close. I don't see any obvious events which would do this, and I've gone about as far as I can when looking through the raw code with DotPeek and I haven't seen anything which even looks promising.

Comment: And before someone offers "lmgtfy", if I knew how to ask Google this question I would have solved this some time ago.

Comment: Could you just use the `Unloaded` Event? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.unloaded.aspx

Comment: @ChrisW. I wish. Unfortunately, Unloaded is called only for objects which are children of the *current window*. This means a modal dialog can't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the answer was there the whole time and I had missed it.

`SheerResponse` has a five parameter version of `ShowModalDialog` which accepts a boolean as a final parameter.  This means I can couple it with `ClientPage.Start`:

```
    Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "Run", kv);
}

private void Run(ClientPipelineArgs args)
{
    var id = args.Parameters["id"];
    if(!args.IsPostBack)
    {
        string controlUrl = string.Format("{0}&id={1}", UIUtil.GetUri("control:AltDelete"), id);
        SheerResponse.ShowModalDialog(controlUrl,"","","",true);
        args.WaitForPostBack();
    }
    else
    {
        Logger.LogDebug("post back");
    }
    Logger.LogDebug("out of if");
}
```